# how do i include a file in my index.php

Tags: php, xml

I have two files :

- index.php
- condition.php

condition.php hold some switch statements. I wrote only one case,but there is more than 20 cases.ow do i include the another file in index.php for showing the output..here is my code:

```
 //index.php    
<?
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=dhaka');
    $information = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information");
    $current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
    $forecast_list = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions");

    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Google Weather API</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1><?= print $information[0]->city['data']; ?></h1>
            <h2>Today's weather</h2>
            <div class="weather">       

                <?php 

                include 'condition.php';
                ?>

                <span class="condition">
                <?= $current[0]->temp_f['data'] ?>&deg; F,
                <?= $current[0]->condition['data'] ?>
                </span>

            </div>

                </body>
    </html>
```

here is the condition.php

```
 switch ($cond) 
            {
                case "Mostly Cloudy":
                    $col="/test/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.png";
                    echo "<img src=\"$col\" alt=\"\"/>";
                    break;

                case "Thunderstorm":
                    $col="/test/images/weather/thunderstorm.png";
                    echo "<img src=\"$col\" alt=\"\"/>";
                    break;}
```

I posted 2 cases but there is more than 20 cases.

Comment: What is not working? It seems to be correct.

Comment: Where is $cond defined? If it's not defined anywhere in your index.php, it won't be defined in condition.php anywhere, and none of your cases would match - other than a `default` case, which means there'd be no output.

Comment: $cond defined in index.php.typing mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the right way using `<?php include("condition.php"); ?>`, all you need to do is define `$cond` so the switch actually does something. Or you can create a function from condition.php and use it that way. That's probably a "cleaner" way to work.

Example:

```
<?php
$cond = "Thunderstorm";
include 'condition.php';
?>
```

Comment: I would still use a function, as this method involves X number of includes as poster stated "20 cases"

Comment: Even better, drop the whole switch and just use the same string names as filenames. Could be done in one line.

Comment: @mat didn't get you.Would please describe it.

Comment: @YasirAdnan : <?php $col="/test/images/weather/".$cond.".png"; ?> the string $cond needs to be the exact same as the image name.

Answer (score 2):

The `include` function includes the code from the included script as if it was written right there, so as long as you declare the `$cond` variable before the `include` statement, this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want a function that you can reuse multiple times:

so your `condition.php` should be:

```
function outputWeather($cond){
   switch ($cond) {
                case "Mostly Cloudy":
                    $col="/test/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.png";
                    echo "<img src=\"$col\" alt=\"\"/>";
                    break;

                case "Thunderstorm":
                    $col="/test/images/weather/thunderstorm.png";
                    echo "<img src=\"$col\" alt=\"\"/>";
                    break;
                  }
}
```

Include that in the `index.php` and just call the function like so in your loop:

```
<?php outputWeather($current[0]->condition['data']); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just include pages in your php by using [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) just like you are doing.

Do make sure though that your `$cond` variable you are using in `conditions.php` is either defined in `index.php` **BEFORE** the include, or is defined in `conditions.php` itself.

```
<?php
   include('condition.php');
?>
```

Anyway an include acts as if the code you include was actually written right where you include it, thus at that very same spot in `index.php`.

Comment: He is already doing that - I am not sure what he is asking, but he has that include line in his code.

Comment: Can i show the switch output??Like the example one in manual.

Comment: Yes you can. You are using `echo ...` in your `conditions.php` so this will just be shown on the webpage as if you wrote it within `index.php`.

Comment: @AaronJSpetner I know. So I don't understand what his question is either. I'm just pointing out it is correct and that he can find more information on the link provided.